# Очистить кэш оптимизаций

Tags: google-chrome, оптимизация, профилирование

С целью корректного замера влияния изменений в коде на производительность первого открытия страницы пользователем, я хочу при каждой загрузке страницы очищать кэш всех оптимизаций скриптов, которые Chrome запомнил с прошлого раза. Это возможно?

А то не хочется каждый раз открывать заново приватное окно и логиниться на сайт...

Comment: Не совсем понятно, где вы проводите замеры, возможно, вам нужна [Очистка кэша и жесткая перезагрузка](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/#throttle). Обратите внимание на третий пункт.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, не уверен. Меня не сетевой кэш интересует, а длительность выполнения обработчика конкретного клика. Замеры произвожу в профайлере хрома.